# How to Enable/Disable a custom chrome extension by clicking an image at the right hand corner of the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to create an addon for chrome which injects javascript code , I am able to add an image which is visible at the right hand corner of the browser, but I want to make the image as a switch which will enable/disable the injection of the javascript, and I'm not able to do this enable/disable part,could any one please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "[content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)" which will listen for a particular event from DOM.

Upon triggering the event, you can [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) the background script to stop its magic (You can even switch the extension icon to indicate that it's disabled).

Example:

**content_script.js:**

```
function setActive(state) {

chrome.extension.sendRequest({ msgType: "setActive", State: state});

return;

}
```

**Background.js:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(

function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(sender.tab.active == false) return;
        var tabId = -1;

        try {
            tabId = sender.tab.id;
        } catch (e) { }
        if (tabId == -1) return;


        switch (request.msgType) {

            case 'setActive':
                if(request.State == 'off') {
                    //Stop extension activity
                    ...
                    //change extension icon to indicate inactivity
                    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                        'path': 'Images/Off.png'
                    });
                }


                break;

        }
});
```

**manifest.json**:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
          "js": ["content_script.js"],
          "run_at":"document_end"
        }
      ],
```